# Iterate a list of types and use it as a generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, generic-list

I am trying to enumerate a list of types in C# and pass these as a generic type. This way I can have one list of object types and use this to sync data, instantiate storage tables, etc. Something like this:

```
public async Task<bool> SyncAll()
{
    var types = new List<Type> { typeof(Product), typeof(Customer) };

    foreach (var t in types)
    {
        await Sync<t>();
    }    
}

public async Task<T> Sync<T>() where T: Syncable
{
    var items = _repository.GetItems<T>();
    ...
}
```

The code above does not work, but is this even possible?

Comment: Not without reflection. Generics are a compile-time feature.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: The answer you marked is instantiating a class with an unknown generic type. That is not what I am trying to accomplish here. I am trying to pass a type from a list as a type into a generic method.

Comment: I updated the duplicate, take a look.